# Add id in a laravel Form to a select list

Tags: php, laravel

I have this form

```
{{ Form::text('username', null, array('class'=>'input-block-level', 'placeholder'=>'Usuario')) }}
    {{ Form::text('firstname', null, array('class'=>'input-block-level', 'placeholder'=>'Nombre')) }}
    {{ Form::text('lastname', null, array('class'=>'input-block-level', 'placeholder'=>'Apellido')) }}
    {{ Form::text('email', null, array('class'=>'input-block-level', 'placeholder'=>'Correo')) }}
    {{ Form::password('password', array('class'=>'input-block-level', 'placeholder'=>'Contraseña')) }}
    {{ Form::password('password_confirmation', array('class'=>'input-block-level', 'placeholder'=>'Confirmar Contraseña')) }}
    {{ Form::select('type', array('01' => 'Busco Trabajo', '02' => 'Ofrezco Trabajo', '03' => 'Busco un Servicio', '04' => 'Ofrezco un Servicio')); }}
    {{ Form::file('image'); }}
```

Works great; but, how can I add an `ID="id"` to the select list? I looked in the Laravel documentation and I can't find anything ...

Thanks.

Comment: You mean html id attribute?

Comment: as simple as that, yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`select` takes 4 params, selected ids being the 3rd, and array of html attributes being th 4th, so this is what you need:

```
{{ Form::select(
    'type', 
    array('01' => 'Busco Trabajo', '02' => 'Ofrezco Trabajo', '03' => 'Busco un Servicio', '04' => 'Ofrezco un Servicio'),
    null,
    array('id' => 'your_id'); }}
```